# Ajax form submitting incrementing times

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I've got a form that submits using ajax, however for some reason if you change the values and submit it again it then it inserts 2 duplicate rows, submit again and it inserts 3 duplicate rows the next time, and so on... Somewhere it's storing the number but being new to ajax i'm not 100% sure what I should or shouldn't be adding. Here's the code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#add-badge-form', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'submit.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data)
        {
            $(".add-badge-result").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                {
                    $(".add-badge-result").html(data);
                });
            $('#add-badge-form').trigger("reset");
       }
    });
    return false;
});
```

EDIT: The PHP that handles the form:

if($_POST['form-name'] == 'add-badge') {

```
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $description = $_POST['description'];
      $level = $_POST['level'];

      $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Badges (Name,Description,Level) VALUES ('$name','$description','$level')") or die(mysql_error());
      mysqli_close($con);

      if($result)
      {
      echo $name." added successfully.";
      }
      else
      {
      echo "Error adding ".$name.".";
      }
```

UPDATE:

I've now found that this only occurs after you change pages (also using ajax). So if you insert a form, then insert again without leaving the page, it works fine. If you insert, then change the page, then go back and insert again, it inserts a duplicate. Here's how I change the page:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".nav li ul a").removeClass("current");

    if (this.id == "add-badge") {
        $("#rightContainer").load("add-badge.php");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    } else if (this.id == "edit-badge") {
        $("#rightContainer").load("edit-badges.php");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    } else if (this.id == "award-badge") {
        $("#rightContainer").load("award-badge.php");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this now. Because of `$(document).on('submit', '#add-badge-form', function(e)` when loading the page, it was loading the instance of the form each time and thus if I loaded the page 5 times, it was having 5 instances of the form. I changed that to `$( "#add-badge-form" ).submit(function(e)` and it now only submits one version no matter how many times the page has been loaded. Simple solution!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommand you to get only the fields you need from your form:

`var data = { field1 : $("#field1").val(), ... };`

This will prevent someone manually adding fields to your form.

I think the way you serialize data is the problem so it should fix it.

Comment: How do I go about receiving those values on submit.php? I've tried a few ways but can't seem to get any result from it at all.

Comment: In my exemple you'll have `$_POST["field1"]` in your PHP

Comment: Just got it working before seeing this, I'd forgotten to pass the form name... I'm still getting the duplicate fields.

Comment: Done. I don't think it's the PHP, I think it's the ajax side of things. I made the name field in the database unique and when it tried to insert a duplicate it flashed up "Name has been inserted" then it quickly vanished and went blank, where it obviously couldn't insert a duplicate. Somewhere along the line the ajax is counting the number of submits and adding an extra one each time.

Comment: I've added an update to the first post with further investigation results.

Comment: Are you using the same form / ajax request for every page?

Comment: For these inserts it is the same page with different data.

Comment: Right, I think I know what the issue is. I think the navigation is opening multiple instances of the form and when you click submit, it's submitting it as many times as the page has been opened. Is there any way to clear which page is loaded here: $("#rightContainer").load("add-badge.php"); ?

Comment: You can remove the content by using `$("#rightContainer").remove()` before loading

Comment: That removes the div so I can't target it, I actually needed `$("#rightContainer").empty();` however whilst that removes the div, the form instance is still loaded, thus I'm still getting 4 forms submitted... If I just click the "Add Badge" button 4 times, I get 4 submissions regardless of how many times I submit the form.

Comment: Ok I think I got it can you show me what you're doing when you load `edit-badges.php` or add badge, whatever

Comment: I have sorted it now, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38610441/1509534